# Guidance on Regex

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I am struggling to complete this regex condition:

"Match anything that is not a legitimate subdomain of rafael.com (including the domain rafael.com)"

For example, these 3 lines should not match because they are legitimate

```
rafael.com
hello.rafael.com
hi.hello.rafael.com
```

And all the lines below should match

```
hello.rafael.xyz
badrafael.com
rafaelbad.com
rafaelbad.xyz
badrafael.xyz
arafael.com
arafael.xyz
rafael.xyz
a.b.rafael.xyz
```

This expression `.*rafael(?!\.com).*` gets me part of the way, but it isn't matching, for example,

```
badrafael.com 
arafael.com
```

I am getting caught up with the lookbehind portion of this regex, I have been staring at this for 3 hours and can't figure it out. Any guidance, suggestions, links to examples would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Is it an option to negate the match afterwards in your programming language? You could look for the "positive" case with `(\.|\b)rafael\.com` and then check in your code, if you "don't".

Comment: @Progman thank you, I certainly can. This implementation of the regex is actually going to be used to block a specific set of domains in MS Exchange. While it won't be implemented in a scripting language per se. I did also think about creating 2 rules to address whatever cases I could not address with the first regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided after much troubleshooting that the best way to do this is actually to create separate regexes for some of the most common scenarios that may come up when blocking domain names and their combinations, and create more than 1 rule, as opposed to trying to capture every single possible combination of a domain in 1 regex.